# Using COUNT and GROUP BY with multiple JOIN tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i want to `JOIN` multiple table and need to `COUNT` from multiple tables using `GROUP BY`

the tables less like this

table A

```
a_id | name          
------------         
1    | john           
2    | david
3    | anna
```

table B

```
b_id | b_title
--------------
1    | b1     
2    | b2     
3    | b3
```

table C

```
c_id | c_title | b_id
------------------------
1    | c1      | 2
2    | c2      | 3
3    | c3      | 1
4    | c4      | 1
```

table D

```
d_id | d_title | c_id | a_id | cost
-----------------------------------
1    | d1      | 3    | 1    | 200
2    | d2      | 1    | 1    | 130
3    | d3      | 2    | 2    | 240
4    | d4      | 2    | 3    | 170
5    | d5      | 4    | 1    | 95
```

what i want is something like this

```
name | COUNT(b_id) | COUNT(d_id) | SUM(cost)
--------------------------------------------
john |      2      |      3      |   425
david|      1      |      1      |   240 
anna |      1      |      1      |   170
```

this is my query

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(d.d_id), SUM(cost)
FROM a INNER JOIN d ON a.a_id = d.a_id
GROUP BY a.a_id
```

I tried but I could not get the correct result of `COUNT(b_id)`

Comment: you need to group by name too

Comment: @Ryan Gadsdon: No. `a.name` is functionally dependent on `a.a_id`. So it's not required to add it to `GROUP BY` - neither by the SQL standard nor by MariaDB.

Answer (score 2):

You want to count distinct `b_id`:

```
SELECT
  a.name, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.b_id),
  COUNT(d.d_id),
  SUM(d.cost)
FROM d 
JOIN a ON a.a_id = d.a_id
JOIN c ON c.c_id = d.c_id
GROUP BY a.a_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add extra `JOIN` to the table `c` like this:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(d.d_id), COUNT(b_id), SUM(cost)
FROM a 
INNER JOIN d ON a.a_id = d.a_id
INNER JOIN c ON c.b_id = d.c_id
GROUP BY a.a_id, a.name
```